# How to create a consecutive between 2 number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, escape-sequences

For example, I have 33 in cell A1, and 40 in cell B1, I want a formula in cell C1, to write an arithmetic sequence from 33 to 40 like this: 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40

[image: example]

Comment: Could you show us your attempts?

Comment: actually the numbers I have like this:
for example: 
33-38 in cell A1, I tried to right this formula: "=RIGHT(B1,2)-LEFT(A1,2)"
the result will be 5, I thought that I can use this number to generate a sequence starting from 33 (5) times to reach to 38

Comment: But I did not find a formula to help me to generate this sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In Office 365:***

```
C1: =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,,A1))
```

[image: sample output]

***Edit:*** If you need to use this in an earlier version of Excel, and your input is a hyphenated string (as you show in your example in your comment) denoting the start and end numbers, try:

```vb
 Option Explicit
 Function Consec(ln As String) As String
    Dim v As Variant, w As Variant
    Dim L As Long, E As Long
    
w = Split(ln, "-")
L = w(0)
E = w(1)

ReDim v(L To E)
For L = L To E
    v(L) = L
Next L

Consec = Join(v, ", ")
End Function
```

eg: `Consec("33-40")` => `33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40`

Comment: It's working perfect on Office 365, thank you, by the way I have to use it on Excel 2013, so I used this code:
Function CONSEC2(ln As Variant)
Dim rn As Integer
rn = 1 * Right(ln, Len(ln) - InStr(1, ln, "-"))
ln = 1 * Left(ln, InStr(1, ln, "-") - 1)
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = ln To rn
        .Add i, True
    Next i
    CONSEC2 = Join(.keys, ", ")
End With
End Function

Comment: @SaherNaji See my edited response for a slightly different method (tested in Windows Excel)